# RecyclerView with multple layout isn't updating properly or crashes on new data

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

So I was creating chat app with firebase and using Realtime database for storing chat and rooms. I created a recyclerview to update the chat ui with a list fetched from the firebase. Data fetching is working fine but updating the ui with new data crashes the app -

here is my adapter -

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private List<Chat> msgList;
    private String user;

    public ChatAdapter(String user,List<Chat> msgList) {
        this.msgList = msgList;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(!msgList.get(position).getUser().equals(user)){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;
        if(viewType==1){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_right,parent,false);
            return new RightChat(view);
        }else{
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_left,parent,false);
            return new LeftChat(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        if(msgList.get(i).getUser().equals(user)) {
            LeftChat viewLeft = (LeftChat) holder;
            viewLeft.msgView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount() - i - 1).getMsg());
            viewLeft.timeView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount() - i - 1).getTime());
        }else{
            RightChat viewRight = (RightChat) holder;
            viewRight.msgView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount()-i-1).getMsg());
            viewRight.timeView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount()-i-1).getTime());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return msgList.size();
    }

    class LeftChat extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView msgView,timeView;
        public LeftChat(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            msgView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
            timeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tm_1);
        }
    }

    class RightChat extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView msgView,timeView;
        public RightChat(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            msgView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
            timeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tm_2);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my pojo class -

```
public class Chat {
    private String msg;
    private String time;
    private String user;

    public Chat() {

    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String stamp) {
        this.time = stamp;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**Error** - *Reyclerview can't cast leftview to rightview and vice-verse.*

What I have tried so far I changed the view in adapter and it worked for the message already in the firebase but as soon as I new message it crashes again. So I don't know where the logic fails. Also I tried adding new data in the firebase manually without the app and it crashes it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some bug in your code, in here

```
    if(msgList.get(i).getUser().equals(user)) {
        LeftChat viewLeft = (LeftChat) holder;
        viewLeft.msgView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount() - i - 1).getMsg());
        viewLeft.timeView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount() - i - 1).getTime());
    }else{
        RightChat viewRight = (RightChat) holder;
        viewRight.msgView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount()-i-1).getMsg());
        viewRight.timeView.setText(msgList.get(getItemCount()-i-1).getTime());
    }
```

you are checking `viewType` by position `i` (`msgList.get(i)` in `if`), but trying to draw item on `getItemCount()-i-1` position in array, so different item, thus `viewType` may mismatch

override `getItem(int position)` method, return `msgList.get(position)` in there, and when you need `msg` then use `getItem` always, e.g. in both `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemViewType` - one unified method for obtaining your models. and don't mix positions, if you get called `onBindViewHolder` with position `i` then use item form position `i`

if you need reverted order just revert order in constructor

Comment: thanks for the reply. The reason I have getcount()-i-1 because I want to show the list in reverse order with the latest one in the bottom like whatsapp. I used to load the list the way you have suggested but it would load my data from top to bottom.

Comment: thats just not logic that you are checking different condition and furter using something different. you are checking `viewType` for position `i` and using mesage from position `getItemCount()-i-1` - these are NOT same items and may need different layouts for shure. I've also wrote that if you need reversed order just change order in constructor. Have you tried any of my suggestions?

Comment: hey sorry but I figured out I can use Collection.reverse() to do that. I don't need to get the item from bottom. Thank you so much

Comment: at first make shure that `if` condition concerns same item/msg you want to draw. glad to hear that now your code works, consider upvoting/accepting my answer if helpful :) good luck!